# Python: How can I make the __Init__ call for two different method of argument?

Tags: python, constructor

I wanna make a **init** method which can understand these contstrutors.

```
candy(name="foo", type="bar")

or pass into a whole dict

candy({"name":"foo" , "type":"bar"})

class candy:
    def __init__ ?????
```

How can I make the **init** method such that accommodate both constructor??

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you know about `**` argument unpacking?

Comment: I think i can use  **kwargs, *args, but not exactly understand how they work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the **init** as normal, for example:

```
class candy(object):
    def __init__(self, name, type):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
```

and then pass arguments in both ways:

```
candy(name='name', type='type')
```

or

```
candy(**{ 'name': 'name', 'type': 'type' })
```

Comment: if there is a lot of argument? can i not just hardcade, name type?

Comment: if `args` is `('name', 'type')` or `['name', 'type']` or something like that, sure.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

and the section immediately preceding it,

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

In your particular case, it might look something like this:

```
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
    if args:
        d = args[0]
        self.name = d['name']
        self.type = d['type']
    else:
        self.name = kwargs['name']
        self.type = kwargs['type']
```

Comment: Hi, for passing the dict into the function, is it a "positional argument"?

Comment: No. It will unpack into keyword args which can be any order

Comment: so for keyword args, that can be into two format, one is a dictionary, another one is "type='abc', name='jdi'" , right?